# Транзакции нет, хотя аннотация @Transactional есть

Tags: java, spring, transaction

При выполнении следующего кода получаю вывод `false`:

```java
@Component
public class SomeNumbersMySQLDao {
    //
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        SomeNumbersMySQLDao dao = context.getBean("someNumbersMySQLDao", SomeNumbersMySQLDao.class);
        dao.insertAnyNumber();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) // on default
    public void insertAnyNumber() {
        System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        //
    }
    //
}
```

Транзакции, разумеется, не работают. Это я понял, когда из метода с транзакцией `required` вызвал метод с транзакцией `never` и не получил ошибку.

Содержание `context.xml`(`SomeNumbersMySQLDao` содержится в пакете `BP`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="BP"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springjdbc?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="1234"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Как сконфигурировано управление транзакциями в `context.xml`?

Comment: @RomanKonoval Никак. Только `bean` `dataSource` определен(не относится к делу) и, конечно, включен скан, под который попадает этот класс(иначе падало бы с ошибкой).

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что существующая конфигурация не предписывает spring-у интерпретировать `@Transactional` аннотации. Нужно сделать как описано в [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations), а именно добавить менеджер транзакций и влючить управление транзакциями с помощью аннотаций:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
<bean id="txManager" 
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Неожиданно. Не всегда нужно на видео-уроки полагаться, оказывается.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, посмотреть еще мой [еще один вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132958/%d0%92%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82) по этой теме. Обычные транзакции работают, но, вот, внутренние - нет(вернее, ведут себя как `Propagation.SUPPORTS`).

Answer (score 1):

В 2020 году стоит уже от XML конфигураций отказаться и использовать `@EnableTransactionManagement`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html