# Внутренние транзакции не работают

Tags: java, spring, transaction

`context.xml`:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="BP"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/><!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springjdbc?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
</bean>
```

Класс, в котором происходит действие(Находится в пакете `BP`):

```
@Configuration
public class SomeNumbersMySQLDao{
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public SomeNumbersMySQLDao(DataSource dataSource){
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        SomeNumbersMySQLDao dao = context.getBean("someNumbersMySQLDao", SomeNumbersMySQLDao.class);

        // код здесь будет изменяться. Назовем ее точкой "main"
    }

    // здесь методы, которые покажу далее.

    public void cleanTable() {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DELETE FROM someNumbers");
    }

    public void printTable() {
        List<Integer> numbersGot = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM someNumbers", Integer.class);
        System.out.println("Numbers got from table: ");
        numbersGot.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Транзакции на одиночных(не вложенных) методах работают.
Приведу пример.
Есть метод:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void outer(int number) {
    System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO someNumbers (number) VALUES (?)", new Object[] {number});
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

В точке "main" пишем следующий код:

```
dao.cleanTable();
dao.outer(123);
```

Выполняем, убираем этот код, пишем следующий код и вновь выполняем:

```
dao.printTable();
```

Получим сначала вывод:

> true

а затем:

> Numbers got from table:

Что понятно, так как транзакция откатилась. Если мы напишем вместо `Propagation.REQUIRED` `Propagation.NEVER`, то получим сначала вывод:

> false

а затем:

> Numbers got from table:
>   123

Что логично - транзакции нет, она и не откатилась.
Более того, если мы напишем вместо `Propagation.REQUIRED` `Propagation.MANDATORY`, то получим однозначный(что одиночные транзакции работают) вывод:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException

Хорошо, теперь попробуем одним методом с `Propagation.REQUIRED` вызвать метод с `Propagation.NEVER`. По идее должны получить ошибку, но этого не происходит.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void outer(int number) {
    System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO someNumbers (number) VALUES (?)", new Object[] {number});
    withNever(number);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
public void withNever(int numberToInsertInInnerMethod) {
    System.out.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO someNumbers (number) VALUES (?)", new Object[] {numberToInsertInInnerMethod});
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Вывод:

> true
>   true
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

а затем:

> Numbers got from table:

Должно было лечь уже на вызове метода `Propagation.NEVER`. И изменения откатились.
Та же картина и с `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`, и с `Propagation.REQUIRED`, и тем более с `Propagation.MANDATORY`.
Однако несколько другие результаты, если поставить на метод `outer` `Propagation.NEVER`. Тогда(пробовал пока только на `Propagation.REQUIRED`, но уверен, что то же будет и с остальными) будет следующий вывод:

> false
>   false
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

И потом:

> Numbers got from table:
>   123
>   123

То есть мои внутренние транзакции по-сути работают как транзакции `Propagation.SUPPORTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Механизм управления транзакциями по умолчанию использует Spring AOP. И в данном случае вы столкнулись с ограничением Spring AOP, а именно, что вложенные вызовы используя `this` этим механизмом не поддерживаются.

Дело в том, что Spring AOP не расширяет класс, а создает для класса обертку (proxy). И в места, где внедряется этот бин или при вызове `getBean` используется именно обертка. Эта обертка и занимается управлением транзакцией, т.е. стартом, фиксированием результата (commit) при успешном выполнении или отменой при ошибке.

При вызове же метода через `this` обертка не используется - это прямой вызов, и соответственно, механизм управления транзакциями не задействуется.

Теперь, когда разобрались с причиной, рассмотрим какие есть варианты это исправить.

### Использование AspectJ вместо Spring AOP

Во-первых, нужно изменить конфигурацию, чтобы механизм управления транзакциями использовал именно AspectJ:

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
```

Далее, нужно задействовать связывание (weaving) для AspectJ. Есть несколько способов это делать, я здесь описывать не буду. Подробности как это делать описаны в документации [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.27.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-configure) и [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.27.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw).

### Изменение структуры кода

Можно изменить структуру кода, чтобы не было вызовов к транзакционным методам внутри одного класса. В данном случае речь идет о том, чтоб перенести `withNever` в отдельный класс.

### Использование самовнедрения (self-injection)

Можно внедрить ссылку на бин в самого себя и использовать ее вместо `this`:

```
public class SomeNumbersMySQLDao{
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private SomeNumbersMySQLDao someNumbersMySQLDao;

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void outer(int number) {
        ...
        someNumbersMySQLDao.withNever(number);
   }

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
   public void withNever(int numberToInsertInInnerMethod) {
       ...
   }
}
```

### Использовать класс посредник

```
@Service
public class TransactionHandler {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public <T> T runInTransaction(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return supplier.get();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    public <T> T runOutOfTransaction(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return supplier.get();
    }
}

public class SomeNumbersMySQLDao{

   @Autowired
   private TransactionHandler transactionHandler;

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void outer(int number) {
        ...
        transactionHandler.runOutOfTransaction(() -> withNever(number));
   }

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
   public void withNever(int numberToInsertInInnerMethod) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Важно, что тут настройки вложенной транзакции определяются не `@Transactional` на `withNever`, а настройками `@Transactoinal` метода `runOutOfTransaction`.

### Использовать ручное управление транзакциями

```
public class SomeNumbersMySQLDao{

   @Autowired
   private TransactionTemplate neverPropagateTransactionTemplate;

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void outer(int number) {
        ...
        neverPropagateTransactionTemplate.execute(() -> withNever(number));
   }

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
   public void withNever(int numberToInsertInInnerMethod) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Нужно понимать, что в этом случае параметры указанные в атрибутах `Transactional`, такие как `propagation`, `isolation` и все другие не учитываются, а берутся те, которые заданы в конфигурации `neverPropagateTransactionTemplate`:

```
<bean id="neverPropagateTransactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="propagationBehaviourName" value="PROPAGATION_NEVER"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Вызов себя действительно сработал. Но мне бы хотелось, чтобы оно само все встраивалось. Поэтому я добавил `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`(включает механизм наследования(`CGLIB`)) и `mode="aspectj"`(включает его для транзакций), но это не сработало. `<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" weaver-class="..."/>`, судя по документации, вовсе не обязателен. Насколько я понял, он лишь оптимизирует процесс. И кидает ошибку `*.NoSuchFieldError: parallelCapableClassLoaderAvailable`, решение которой не нашел(что-то про последнюю версию пишут, но, думаю, это неактуально).