# Entity отваливается от управления Spring Data во время транзакции

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Имеется обычный бин спринга. В нем некий метод, не отмеченный аннотацией @Transactional, дергает метод приведенный ниже:

```
@Transactional //spring tx, not javax
public void saveSubCategories(int id, ...) {
    Optional<Category> optionalCategory = categoryRepository.findById(id);
    //some code
    Category category = optionalCategory.get();
    List<SubCategory> dbSubCategories = category.getSubCategories();
    int size = dbSubCategories.size();
    ///some code
```

Любое взаимодействие с `dbSubCategories` (для примера взял получение размера списка) вызывает LazyInitException.

Jpa entity настроены так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    //fields and getters/setters

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<SubCategory> getSubCategories() { return subCategories; }

    public void setSubCategories(List<SubCategory> subCategories) { this.subCategories = subCategories; }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subcategory")
public class SubCategory {
    //fields and getters/setters

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    public Category getCategory() { return category; }

    public void setCategory(Category category) { this.category = category; }
```

Также пожалуй важно заметить что в бд таблица subcategory пуста, т.е. должно бы просто вернуть size = 0;

Если поставить в Category `fetch = EAGER` то работает корректно.
В ходе экспериментов также выяснилось что если в том же методе дальше выполнить

```
SubCategory subCategory = new SubCategory();
subCategory.setCategory(category);
subCategoryRepository.save(subCategory);
```

То все падает с ошибкой `springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException ... detached entity passed to persist: entity.Category`

Как это так? Транзакция ведь не закрыта, все выполняется в одном методе, но объект category отваливается от управления jpa.

И как избежать использования `fetch = EAGER`? И почему падает LazyInit во время транзакции?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Транзакции нет, хотя аннотация @Transactional есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130191/%d0%a2%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-transactional-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c) Не настроены транзакции, т.е. `@Transactional` аннотации не достаточно, нужно чтоб кто-то ее обрабатывал.

Comment: У меня включен @EnableTransactionManagement. XML конфига нет.

Comment: Может к вас и есть какие-то аннотации, но симптомы ошибки говорят о том, что транзакция в методе помеченным `@Transactional` не создается. Так что нужно показать, как у вас сконфигурированы транзакции. И проверить, что транзакция создалась (это видно по стеку вызовов - там будет прокси соответствующий).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывается:

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations